# List(Of String) into List(Of integer) with Splitting in VB.Net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list

I have a List of String:

```
Dim values as List(Of String) = {{1 ; 4} , {2 ; 8} , {3 ; 16}}
```

This list was created by a previous existing code (so I didn't define it as a list of strings by myself).

So when I type

```
MsgBox(values(0))
'Output: 1 ; 4
```

this shows up.

Those values correspond to xy-Values, so what I want to have is something like this

```
MsgBox(xVal(0))
'Output: 1
MsgBox(yVal(2))
'Output: 16
```

I have been looking for a solution for quite a while now, scince VB.net is quite new for me. The main problem here is the conversion between the types. Would appreciate any kind of help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the List to x, y array like below

```
Dim xval as new List(Of Integer)
Dim yVal as new List(Of Integer)
For Each v in values
    xval.add(v.Split(";")(0))
    yval.add(v.Split(";")(1))
Next
' Prinitng as you tested, 
Console.WriteLine(xval(0))
Console.WriteLine(yval(2))
```

you can use the xVal, yVal arrays for processing your business logic

Comment: thank you!  First, it didn't work for me. But when I change xVal and yVal to a List of Object, everything is fine. Otherwise it says "System.OverflowException" for whatever reason

Answer (score 2):

> Those values correspond to xy-Values

Here's an example using [ConvertAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.convertall?view=net-5.0) to get a `List` of [Point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point?view=net-5.0):

```
Dim values As New List(Of String)({"1 ; 4", "2 ; 8", "3 ; 16"})
Dim coords As List(Of Point) = values.ConvertAll(Of Point)(Function(ByVal input As String)
                                                               Dim data() As String = input.Split(";")
                                                               Return New Point(CInt(data(0)), CInt(data(1)))
                                                           End Function)
For Each pt As Point In coords
    Debug.Print(pt.X & ", " & pt.Y)
Next
```

Output:

```
1, 4
2, 8
3, 16
```

I didn't include any error checking on the data.  It assumes each string has a semi-colon and that the elements in the first two positions of the resulting array are valid integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split function :

```
MsgBox(values(0).Split(";")(0).Trim) 'For the X in values(0)
MsgBox(values(0).Split(";")(1).Trim) 'For the Y in values(0)
```

Split(";") will split your string in an array with the ";" as delimiter.
[image: Example]

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.split?view=net-5.0

Trim is used to remove spaces :

```
Dim a_string as string = " 7 "
MsgBox(a_string.Trim) 'Output : "7"
```

---

> In your example :

```
MsgBox(values(0).Split(";")(0).Trim)
'Output: 1
MsgBox(values(2).Split(";")(1).Trim)
'Output: 16
```